# SQL How can I return an empty array when all values are null?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I select some tables with json_agg and json_build, all works but I got some data that I dont want it,

My product_media (pm) is empty there are no images, if I use json_agg(json_build_object)) then I got 3x times all rows with null like this:

```
  product_media: [
    {
      id: null,
      src: null,
      alt: null,
      s_position: null,
      updated_at: null
    },
    {
      id: null,
      src: null,
      alt: null,
      s_position: null,
      updated_at: null
    },
    {
      id: null,
      src: null,
      alt: null,
      s_position: null,
      updated_at: null
    }
  ],
```

how can I say when id is null then dont show it or when no product media was found then make an empty array ?

code:

```
      SELECT 

      p.id,
      p.shop_id,
      p.provider_id,
      p.name,
      p.status,

      json_agg(json_build_object(
        'id', pt.id,
        'tag', pt.tag
      )) AS tags,

      json_agg(json_build_object(
        'id', pm.id,
        'src', pm.src,
        'alt', pm.alt,
        's_position', pm.s_position,
        'updated_at', pm.updated_at
      )) AS product_media

      po.id as po_id,
      po.name,
      po.position,

      pov.id as pov_id,
      pov.value,

      pv.id as pv_id,
      pv.quantity,
      pv.price,
      pv.is_male,
      pv.shipping_price,
      pv.grams,
      pv.weight,
      pv.weight_unit,
      pv.length,
      pv.s_position,
      pv.option_1,
      pv.option_2,
      pv.option_3

      FROM product p

      LEFT JOIN product_media pm
      ON pm.p_id = p.id

      LEFT JOIN product_options po
      ON po.p_id = p.id

      LEFT JOIN product_options_value pov
      ON pov.p_o_id = po.id

      LEFT JOIN product_tags pt
      ON pt.p_id = p.id

      LEFT JOIN product_variants pv
      ON pv.p_id = p.id

      WHERE p.provider_id = $1
      
      GROUP BY 
        p.id,
        pm.id,
        po.id,
        pov.id,
        pv.id
        
      LIMIT 1;
```

I am very thankful for your help I dont know what to do or how to do it

Comment: You use `left join` to `product` table for all other tables in the query. That specifically says to return null values where there is no matching row for any given `product.id`. This may be why you get null values. Try changing `left join' to just 'join'.

Comment: @Belayer if I use only JOIN then no row was found

Comment: That means you do not have data in any of the other tables matching the specified `product.id` (i.e. $1).  You need to post sample data and table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
json_agg(
    CASE WHEN pm.id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE
      json_build_object(
        'id', pm.id, 
        'src', pm.src,
        ...
      ) END
  ) AS product_media
```

This will check if `pm.id` is `NULL`, and if so return `NULL` instead of building the `JSON` object.

so you are looking to get an empty array when there is `NULL` value. you can update your query with this

use `COALESCE` to convert a `NULL` to an empty array

```
COALESCE(
    json_agg(
      CASE WHEN pm.id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE
        json_build_object(
          'id', pm.id,
          'src', pm.src, 
          'alt', pm.alt
        )
      END
    ),
    '[]'
  ) AS product_media
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment now I got this: product_media: [ null, null, null ], can it not be an empty array ?

Comment: @Jsjs take a look answer I have added use `COALESCE` to convert a `NULL` to an empty array i believe this should give you a result which you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`json_strip_nulls()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
      json_agg(json_strip_nulls(json_build_object(
        'id', pm.id,
        'src', pm.src,
        'alt', pm.alt,
        's_position', pm.s_position,
        'updated_at', pm.updated_at
      ))) AS product_media
```

If you can work with `jsonb` instead of `json`, that would be preferred ([more space efficient](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html)).  If you choose to use `jsonb`, then you can use `jsonb_strip_nulls()` instead.

Comment: I have regular columns no json or jsonb column but I convert it to json to become an array of objects, but this gives me not want I want I need an empty array